# How to disable hyperlink based on condition in kendo ?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am getting flag `ratingStatusKey` from back-end if its `RA_RT_Edit` i want to show add/edit link and if its non-editable status i want to hide it this is implemented on kendo grid but its not working , Any idea what i am doing wrong..

config.js

```
 columns: [{
                    field: '',
                    title: 'Action',
                    width: '8em',
                    template: '<a href="" ng-click="addEditAttestor(this.dataItem)" require-control-point="ATTESTATION_ADD,ATTESTATION_EDIT"># if (ratingStatusKey === \'RA_RT_EDITABLE\'){# <span>Add/Edit</span> # } #</a>'
                },{
                    field: 'ratingDateHistory',
                    title: 'History',
                    width: '8em'
                }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with kendo, but have you tried changing the 'if' to 'ng-if'?

ngIf is a directive that only displays an element if the expression evaluates to truthy

so you might add an attribute to the  element like so:

```
ng-if="ratingStatusKey==='RA_RT_EDITABLE'"
```